# Is putting an authentication tokens inside the HTML body safe?

Tags: authentication, api

I have a project, a webapp/website that uses cookies to authenticate users with long randomly generated strings (also with samesite:lax, httponly, secure), however I also have an API which itself needs authentication tokens.

My current design is when the website server authenticates the user it generates the API authToken and injects along with the total initial state of the page. Then the API requests are served with this authToken. Is this flow inherently flawed?

I thought of using an extra HTTP request after page loading to get the API authToken and thus avoid putting it inside the HTML body but that means more slowness since the page contents is usually dependent on the API requests which need an extra HTTP request after the page load to get the API authToken.

I assume the connection is already over HTTPS of course.

Comment: You might want to clarify a bit, but typically headers are used for transporting authentication tokens as it leaves the values inaccessible from JavaScript

Comment: of course the API authToken is put into an HTTP header, my question is about whether obtaining the authToken inside the first load of the web page inside the HTML body is safe in the first place.

Comment: API security can be highly implementation specific so you need to clarify. Is there a reason the token can't be in th response headers rather than the body?

Comment: @wireghoul I think you didn't get my question, the API authTokens needs to be fetched after the authentication from the first load in the website, I can't get it from some response header. But the authToken is of course used in request headers once it is obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best. Defeats the whole reason behind httponly cookies. Namely any JavaScript can read the token and exfiltrate it. It adds a lot of complexity to your threat model.

Instead use the cookie and host the api and static page from the same domain name.

If you cannot redesign the API, then proxy requests from the client -> your frontend -> the api.

When the client hits https://your_frontend/api/* -> you first check their cookie, then you read the API token from your server, append it to the API headers, and *proxy* the request to the API server.

Comment: Thank you, my concern is definitely is about some malicious code in the browser that can read javascript inside the page, but I cannot control the API design, its authentication token must be put in a header since it can be accessed from any client not just browsers. So the cookie is only used for the website and then the authentication token for the API is obtained if the cookie is authenticated.

Comment: Then proxy the api requests through your front end. Updated the answer with the design.

Answer (score 1):

Using API tokens in headers is very common and a fine solution to the authentication problem. Having them inside the HTML-body is also fine. So I would say that the answer to your question is yes.

But what about XSS and the HTTP-only flag?

If the API needs to have the token in a header on every request, you need to insert it on every request using JS or similar. So you won't be able to get the benefits of HTTP-only here. If you get it on the first page load or in a second request doesn't really matter.

Is loosing the benefits of HTTP-only bad? Maybe a little, but I would not worry to much about it anyway. The HTTP-only flag only provided a defence in depth that wasn't to valuable anyway, so I wouldn't cry over it. You slay the XSS dragon using systematic coding practices and well designed libraries, not by using a single flag.